# Call array variable inside of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to call array variable inside the current array. Something like this:

```
$conv= array (
"hello" => array("Hello", "Hi", "Hello, how are you?"),
"helo" => array_merge($conv['hello'])
);
print_r($conv['helo']);
```

How can I do this.
thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output from your print_r?

Comment: My expected output is:

`Array
(
    [hello] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello
            [1] => Hi
            [2] => Hello, how are you?
        )

    [helo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello
            [1] => Hi
            [2] => Hello, how are you?
        )

)`

thanks

Comment: So your `helo` is an exact copy of `hello`?

Comment: Yes bro. Its possible?

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: @AlAmin: Ehhh... and reason for do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define your function directly when you create the array, then you need to declare `helo` value as [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), refer current array as global variable and return something you need

```
$conv = array(
"hello" => array("Hello", "Hi", "Hello, how are you?"),
"helo" => function() {
        global $conv;
        return array_merge($conv['hello'], array("Bye", "See you"));
    }
);
print_r($conv['helo']());
```

Note that when you need the value returned from that function you need to call it as a function like above `$conv['helo']()` while calling just `$conv['helo']` will return a `Closure` object.

**UPDATE**

According to what you're asking in comments, it seems that you just want to get a copy of `hello` value through a function

```
$conv = array(
"hello" => array("Hello", "Hi", "Hello, how are you?"),
"helo" => function() {
        global $conv;
        return $conv["hello"];
    }
);
print_r($conv['helo']());
```

Comment: Hello Drkey,

Your solution is fine and may be work for me. But I want make it above way. is it possible? 

thanks

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I understood what exactly you mean with "above way". What do you expect to do and get?

Comment: That's, which I mentioned in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to build the array is probably impossible.
Because the array is not made untill the end of the function `;` when you try to set 'helo', 'hello' is undefined.

You need to set 'hello' first then copy it to 'helo'.

```
$conv = array("hello" => array("Hello", "Hi", "Hello, how are you?"));

$conv["helo"] = $conv['hello'];
print_r($conv['helo']);
```

https://3v4l.org/PCJH7

Comment: Thank you vqdave could not get it right on my phone.

Comment: No problem, I have the same problem all the time!